# Rails naming conventions for models with forbidden names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, naming-conventions

I'm writing a rails application, and I need to name one of my model Test, and inside that model I need a class attribute - when I tried the first one, I couldn't run any UT since Test ceased to be a module - so I ranamed to Tst. I haven't even tried naming a column class - I went with clss. What names would you use? Are there any conventions known amongs RoR developers for such situations?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen anything for Test but class is typically changed to klass.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby and Rails have several different objects part of a standard library. You cannot use an already-defined class name as name for your models.

For instance, you cannot call a model `Thread` or `Object` because Ruby already defines a `Thread` and `Object` class.
Likewise, Ruby has a library called `Test::Unit` so you can't use the `Test` namespace as model name.

There isn't a real full list of reserve objects because it really depends on your current environment. However, in order to successfully use Rails, you should at least have a basic Ruby knowledge so that you know the names of the most common standard library classes.

Comment: I'm not asking whether I can or cannot use those names - I ask how to name them instead and are there any best known practices to follow.

Answer (score 0):

I've run up against this a few times (writing educational software--where you regularly want to model 'tests' :-). Depends exactly what you're modeling I suppose, but I usually opt for 'quiz' to avoid conflicts. I'd love to hear a better solution, since I find 'quizzes' an awkward plural.

Like dj2 said, class is usually done as 'klass'.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following page for Rails reserved words: http://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/ None of these words should be used as class or attribute name.